# 14.04.1 server install without internet access

Tags: 14.04, server, system-installation, internet, iso

This question has been asked twice before on this forum, 6 months ago and 1 year ago, no solution was given.  My problem is the same.  I downloaded ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso and used unetbootin (also tried Universal-USB-installer) to write a bootable UBS stick.  I booted, chose "expert commandline install" and I get stuck at "download installer components from mirror site".

Is there really no way to install the server without a network connection?  I was able to install the desktop version with no problems, but it will take me hours to remove all the packages I don't want to have on this system.

This installation will be dedicated to servicing a neutron detector and I need it to be headless with command-line only. It will be setup to serve data (huge amounts) when requested. It is on a private network but cannot be connected to the internet even for installation.

If anyone can give me a hint on how to do this, I will be very grateful.

--Lee

Comment: Hi chaskes.  Thanks for helping me.  The name of the image I am using is ubuntu-14.04.1-server-amd64.iso.  I don't have a clear understanding of which installer I am using. The installer looks different depending on whether I create the bootable USB stick using unetbootin or Universal-USB-Installer.  I am a physicist and I use Linux systems to control my experiments, but I'm not an expert on its inner workings.

Comment: Hi chaskes.  YEs, my system uses UEFI.  If I turn UEFI off then the installer hangs.  With UEFI turned on, it boots into GRUB and I run the installer from there.  I have a 12.04 box here so I will try making the USB stick with dd.

Comment: I downloaded the image from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/install-ubuntu-server

Comment: Hi chaskes.  You are 100% correct.  I created a bootable USB installer on my Ubuntu 12.04 box and the installer ran without any issues at all.  I am up and running.  One note -- it did not work until I also reformatted the USB stick on the Linux box.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely caused by using unetbootin or the Universal-USB-Installer. EFI booting has complicated the installation procedure and these utilities are known to sometimes have problems creating an-EFI installer correctly.

There's really no longer any reason not to simply use `dd` to create the USB installer, especially since you already have a working Ubuntu workstation.

First, use `gparted` or `Disks` to reformat the USB stick that you have been using, otherwise it is possible that old, remaining data will cause problems. (I once had a package checksum mismatch error from this problem during installation.)

Then:

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/iso of=/path/to/usb
```

Be *very* careful to check what you typed before hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Any data in the `of=` path *will* be destroyed.

Comment: And an upvote!  Good to know! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Server edition installation without a network connection is a standard release test case. The procedure is documented, and I observe a revision edit was just done in late January, 2014. [The test case](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/testcases/1441/info). If required I'll figure out how to copy the content herein.

Comment: Hi Doug.  Thanks for your answer.  I ran across the test case you pointed me to early on in my effort.  I followed the steps exactly to the best of my ability.  When I get to step 11, the DHCP request fails as it should and I select "Do not configure network at this time".  The very next thing it does is insist that I connect to the Ubuntu archive.  I cannot get past this.  Some of the preceding steps are in a different order from what is listed.  As chaskes suggested, I might be using the wrong installer.  When running the installer it says "[?] Ubuntu Installer main menu" at the top.

Comment: I am installing right now on a quest VM, however I created one with no network card at all. It is installing fine. I'll do it again, specifying a network card but pointing it to my host LAN instead of host side WAN.

Comment: I have [this screen](http://hussainweb.me/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/08-ubuntu-menu.png) at the start (well almost, I'm not using virtualBox).

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant by "[!] Ubuntu installer main menu", and yes the installation process falls to that menu when something does not go smoothly. I am at the "Configure the package manager step"

Comment: Hi Doug.  Yes, I get that screen when I boot with UEFI turned off but the system hangs up immediately so I can't run the installer.  When I turn UEFI on, it starts up with GRUB and I run the Ubuntu installer form there.  My system is a INTEL D2500CC MB with the Atom D2500 processor.  It uses the NM10 chipset and has the most recent BIOS update from INTEL.

Comment: Hi Lee, I'm going to have to defer to input from others. I am only familiar with booting directly into the .iso, not some option from grub. I have installed my VM 3 times now: No NIC, a NIC that accidentally had internet access and got an IP address from DHCP; A NIC that couldn't get a DHCP address (your case). They all worked fine.

Comment: Hi Doug.  Thanks for your help.  I followed chaskes suggestion and made the USB boot installer using dd on one of my other Linux boxes and everything just worked.  I was not getting a good boot image from either unetbootin or Universal-USB-Installer.  Thanks again.